# Find first comma in string, then extract value between spaces

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm extracting rows from a txt file.

This row contains values like this:

```
 DESCRIPTION 1    1.234,00    15.980,00 [etc.]
```

I would like to extract these values (I mean only numeric values).

So I thought to find first comma, execute a for cycle backwards until first White space and execute a For cycle forward for decimals digits.
The I should go to the second comma and perform these cycles again.

Can you suggest some code that could be useful for my solution?

Comment: Are the columns fixed width?  In other words, does the data on all the columns line up with each other left-to right?

Comment: Can you show us a few more rows of data, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you also need that first `1`? Why not loop through the line (forward only), looking for digits, dots and commas and process the collected digits (etc) once you find something else (like a space)?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I don't need "1" in "Description 1". Columns are fixed, but not with tabulation. So I don't have a specified number of White spaces between one column and another.

Comment: Do you need the two numbers after the comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, if you just need the decimal number before the comma, then you can do this with a pretty simple regex:

```
Dim s = "DESCRIPTION 1    1.234,00    15.980,00"
Dim pattern = "\d+(\.\d+)?,\d+"
Dim matches = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(s, pattern)

For Each match in matches
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value)
Next

'Outputs:
'
'1.234,00
'15.980,00
```

---

Here's a quick breakdown of the regex:

- `\d+` - `\d` is shorthand for `[0-9]`, which just means "any numeric character". The `+` just indicates "one or more"
- `\.` - this just matches a period character.
- `,` - this just matches a comma.
- `( ... )` - parentheses just creates a group (think of it as a sub-regex)
- `?` - question marks mean that the previous item is optional. In this case, that means that the group matching `(\.\d+)?` is optional, which allows you to match both `0.000,00` and `0,00`

In that regex, if the comma and period are optional, then you can add a `?` after them.

Comment: This is working great! But just only one question. If I need to extract also values like this: 0,00? I marked as required the comma. But the first d+ (before dot) is the key of my question, i think.

Comment: @s.milziadi, For that you want to group the `\.\d+` part and make it optional: `"\d+(\.\d+)?,\d+"` I'll update the answer for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be needing to look at `System.Text.Regex`.

```
Match m = Regex.Match("DESCRIPTION 1    1.234,00    15.980,00", ".*?( [0-9]*?.(?'n1'[0-9]+),(?'n2'[0-9]+)))
While m.Success
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(m.Groups["n1"].Value + "  "+m.Groups["n2"].Value);

    m = m.NextMatch()
End While
```

Comment: Although I suspect you might be correct, this is not really helpful as an answer.  If somebody doesn't know what regular expressions are, just mentioning the namespace (not even linking it to MSDN) really isn't going to help the OP

Comment: Sorry, I was in the middle of trying out the Regex Expression

Comment: Fair enough @Chris, I will be happy to remove the down-vote once you've edited your answer with something suitable.  Although I would definitely wait to see if the OP responds to the comment about fixed width definition

Comment: I converted it to VB.NET.  An explanation of how the regex expression works, for the given situation, is usually a good idea, especially when you don't know if the OP is familiar with RegEx.

Comment: @StevenDoggart, the double slashes aren't required for VB.NET regex since VB.NET strings don't recognize escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

My Visual Basic knowledge is pretty limited, but can't you utilize the `IsNumeric` function available in VB.NET?

Someting like this:

```
' initial string/row/etc
    Dim s As String = "DESCRIPTION 1 1.234,00 15.980,00"

    ' Split string based on spaces
    Dim words As String() = s.Split(New Char() {" "c})
    ' Use For Each loop over split and display them
    Dim word As String
    For Each word In words
        If IsNumeric(word) Then
            Console.WriteLine(word & " is numeric")
        Else
           Console.WriteLine(word & " is not numeric")
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

If the columns are fixed width, you can get the values like this:

```
Dim input As String = "DESCRIPTION 1    1.234,00    15.980,00"
Dim col1 As String = input.SubString(17, 12).Trim()
Dim col2 As String = input.SubString(29).Trim()
```

Comment: And what happens if the first decimal number has digits in the tens place?

Comment: @valverij According to the OP, the columns are fixed width, which means each column starts at the same character position.  As such, if the first number contains a digit in the tens place, it would still start at the same character position, but it would extend one character further to the right (narrowing the gap between the two numbers.  In that case, my example still works perfectly fine.